# Adding a letter to a counter

Tags: counters, amsthm

I would like to number my definitions and theorems etc. "N1, N2, N3, ..." throughout my document, ignoring section numbers etc. Is there a way that I can tell amsthm to number them this way?

Comment: `\renewcomand\thethm{N\arabic{thm}}`  if you are using a `thm` counter.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle please post that answer as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can declare `\renewcomand\thethm{N\arabic{thm}}` if you are using a `thm` counter.